# Android Facebook SDK - Like Button(for URL)

Tags: android, facebook-like, android-facebook

I know that it is not possible to use Android Facebook SDK to like pages. But what about URLS if I have my own site that I would like people to like.

Can I use Android Facebook SDK for that and how?

Comment: Have u found a solution?